# Error after applying lm in loop

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to apply the following code and it works fine with any data without NA value. however, when I include data with NA values I receive the following message:

`Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases`

the code I use is :

```
    m <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 5, nrow = length(unique(df$Year))*length(unique(df$Firm))))
    enter code here
l = 0
for(i in unique(df$Year)) {
  for(j in unique(df$Firm)) {
    l = l + 1
    mod<-lm(Ri ~ RM + Rz, data = df, subset = df$Year==i & df$Firm ==j)
    m[l,] <- c(i,
               as.character(j), 
               mod$coefficients[2],
               mod$coefficients[3],
               summary(mod)$sigma)
  }
}
names(m) <- c("Year", "Firm", "B1", "B2","e")
```

this is an example about the data I am using:

```
Year   Firm    Ri    Rm    Rz
2009   A       30    55    NA
2009   A       0     55    NA
2009   A       1     55    NA
2010   A       7     55    85
2010   A       15    NA    85
2011   A       0     55    85
2011   A       3.5   55    85
2011   A       8     NA    85
2009   B       24    55    85
2009   B       30    55    85
2009   B       25    55    85
2010   B       5.2   NA    85
2010   B       11.8  55    85
2011   B       0     55    NA
2011   B       90    55    NA
2011   B       57    55    NA
```

Any Suggestions ???

Comment: How about you try `data = subset(df, .....)`?

Comment: If you post a sample of your data frame `df`, there may be an even better piece of code people can help you with.

Comment: thank you @Gopala for the suggestion

Comment: did you try using `na.action=na.omit`, in the `lm fit` function ?

Comment: @user5249203 the same error

Comment: Your problem is that there are no values for Rz for Year == 2009 & Firm == 'A' (similarly for 2011 and 'B'). So, `lm` is not able to do anything. If you impute `85` for example, you can see it works. However, it only fits intercept because all values are same.

Comment: @Gopala thank you, I think this is the problem, but can I ask R to continue  the code and ignore these values?? for example, exclude Year == 2009 & Firm == 'A' and continue with other years and firms.

Comment: Added that option as an UPDATE below...take a look. You need to filter out cases where all values are NAs in either of the two columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aside from the data problem above, you can re-write your code as follows using a combination of `dplyr` and `broom` packages:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df$Rz <- 85 # Imput values of Rz to make the code work
df %>% group_by(Year, Firm) %>% do(tidy(lm(Ri ~ Rm + Rz, data = .)))

Source: local data frame [6 x 7]
Groups: Year, Firm [6]

   Year   Firm        term estimate std.error statistic     p.value
  <int> <fctr>       <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>
1  2009      A (Intercept) 10.33333  9.837570  1.050395 0.403735888
2  2009      B (Intercept) 26.33333  1.855921 14.188819 0.004930448
3  2010      A (Intercept)  7.00000       NaN       NaN         NaN
4  2010      B (Intercept) 11.80000       NaN       NaN         NaN
5  2011      A (Intercept)  1.75000  1.750000  1.000000 0.500000000
6  2011      B (Intercept) 49.00000 26.286879  1.864048 0.203331016
```

UPDATE: Adding a filter option so that the groups of Year/Firm that don't have all NAs in one of the other (independent variables) can be fit using `lm`:

```
df %>% group_by(Year, Firm) %>% filter(!all(is.na(Rm)) & !all(is.na(Rz))) %>% do(tidy(lm(Ri ~ Rm + Rz, data = .)))
Source: local data frame [4 x 7]
Groups: Year, Firm [4]

   Year   Firm        term estimate std.error statistic     p.value
  <int> <fctr>       <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>
1  2009      B (Intercept) 26.33333  1.855921  14.18882 0.004930448
2  2010      A (Intercept)  7.00000       NaN       NaN         NaN
3  2010      B (Intercept) 11.80000       NaN       NaN         NaN
4  2011      A (Intercept)  1.75000  1.750000   1.00000 0.500000000
```

This output shows only an intercept model fit since there is no other variability in the provided sample data. However, if you had such variability (for example on `mtcars` data set), you will get output as follows:

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% do(tidy(lm(mpg ~ wt + am, data = mtcars)))
Source: local data frame [9 x 6]
Groups: cyl [3]

    cyl        term    estimate std.error   statistic      p.value
  <dbl>       <chr>       <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>
1     4 (Intercept) 37.32155131 3.0546385 12.21799285 5.843477e-13
2     4          wt -5.35281145 0.7882438 -6.79080719 1.867415e-07
3     4          am -0.02361522 1.5456453 -0.01527855 9.879146e-01
4     6 (Intercept) 37.32155131 3.0546385 12.21799285 5.843477e-13
5     6          wt -5.35281145 0.7882438 -6.79080719 1.867415e-07
6     6          am -0.02361522 1.5456453 -0.01527855 9.879146e-01
7     8 (Intercept) 37.32155131 3.0546385 12.21799285 5.843477e-13
8     8          wt -5.35281145 0.7882438 -6.79080719 1.867415e-07
9     8          am -0.02361522 1.5456453 -0.01527855 9.879146e-01
```

EDIT: Adding a simple example that proves the problem in the original post:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- 1:10
z <- NA
df <- data.frame(x = x, y = y, z = z)
lm(x ~ y + z, data = df)
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases
```